# How to get imageURL of PictureBox in C# when ImageLocation doesn't work?

Tags: c#, picturebox

How to get the image URL of a picture box in windows form when ImageLocation doesn't work?

```
string filepath = picturebox.ImageLocation; // Returns null
```

Comment: If the user loads the image to picturebox via PictureBox.Image, then Imagelocation is always NULL. so you cant get the path

Comment: please show some source code of how you load the image into the picturebox

Answer (score 2):

If you use the ImageLocation property of picturebox to load the image, then you get what you want. Other wise if you load it via Image property then you wont get from ImageLocation and neither from Image again.

Answer (score 1):

you can get that via

```
string filepath = PictureBox.ImageLocation;
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation.aspx

Comment: If the user loads the image to picturebox via PictureBox.Image, then Imagelocation is always NULL. so you cant get the path.

Comment: that's true - although that is NOT done by the user but by the developer... since I suspect that the OP is the developer this should be no real issue regarding to this question...

Comment: Im sorry, i meant OP = User = Developer, etc.

Comment: but then he would know that he did load it via Image and that the location must be somewhere available where he constructed/loaded the image in his code...

Comment: All i am saying most developers load the image to picturebox via Image property than Imagelocation. But see the OP has commented to 1 of the answer post here saying ImageLocation not working, that means he has used Image property

Answer (score 0):

ImageLocation

```
PictureBox.ImageLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this post can help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2007/06/15/data-binding-a-winforms-picturebox-to-a-file-path-or-url.aspx

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need:

```
Picturebox.ImageLocation
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how you are loading the image into the picture box?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution. Store the path of the `Image` in the `Tag` property of the picture box, when we select the image.

```
pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(oOpenFileDialog.FileName);
pictureBox2.Tag = oOpenFileDialog.FileName;
```

And retrive it when you need it:

```
string Path = pictureBox2.Tag + string.Empty;
```

Remember, you have to set the `Tag` property to `null` on clearance.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an Image to PictureBox has a certain methodology to be done correctly.
I'm sure you'll understand the reason and logic behind using the **PictureBox.ImageLocation** after reading this answer.

When you get an **Image.FromFile**; you will be required to specify a string, containing the file: Directory, FileName and Extension of the selected Image.
Therefore, once you select/load the Image to be loaded (assuming you'll be using OpenFileDialog); you have to set the file full path to the **PictureBox.ImageLocation** property in first place (this way you will be able to retrieve it whenever needed); and only then (preferably) you can load the Image to your PictureBox.

See example bellow:

```
   // Dispose PictureBox Image (Prepare it to load another Image).
    private void DisposeImage()
    {
        if (pictureBox.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox.Image = null;
            pictureBox.ImageLocation = null;
            pictureBox.Update();
        }
    }
    

   // 1. Make sure that no Image is Loaded before Loading a new Picture.
   // 2. Set the Image Location to PictureBox.ImageLocation
   // 3. Load the Image.FromFile (Get the string from stored value).
   private void SetImage(string imageFile)
   {
       // Clear any existant Image in PictureBox.
       // [Defensive programming to prevent exceptions]
       DisposeImage();
    
       // Check if full path is valid (File Exists).
       if File.Exists(imageFile))
       {
           // Store the Image location to variable.
           pictureBox.ImageLocation = imageFile;
           
           // Load the Image from stored variable.
           pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(pictureBox.ImageLocation);
       }

       // Set an Image (representing "no image"); in case the Selected Image Does not exist or fails to load.
       else { pictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.NoImageAvailable; }

       // Place your Image Configuration to Adjust to PictureBox Here.
       pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    }
```

In case you require to get the PictureBox Image Location:

```
    // Retrieve Current PictureBox Image Location (if any).
    private string GetImageLocation()
    {
        // Set the default Image Location value (empty).
        // This is usefull to check wether the string is empty or not.
        // This can obviously be improved (I removed some unnecessary parts to suit this exmaple).
        string fullPath = string.Empty;

        // Make sure stored Image Location string is NOT Null or Empty.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureBox.ImageLocation))
        {
            // Assign the Image Location to the local variable (to be returned).
            fullPath = pictureBox.ImageLocation;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }
```

After you write this down;you get the logic and it ends up in being really easy.